# Two Pane View control not working as expected

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

According to the Microsoft documentation, it states the following for the Two Pane View:

```
 By default, Pane1Length is set to Auto and it sizes itself to fit its content. Pane2Length is set to * and it uses all the remaining space.
```

With the following code, I don't see that defualt behavior being applied. Am I missing some extra properties I need to explicitly set? My end goal is simply for Pane1 to always show on a Single screen device, and hide Pane2.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <muxc:TwoPaneView x:Name="MyTwoPaneView">
        <muxc:TwoPaneView.Pane1>
            <Grid x:Name="Pane1Root"
                  Background="Orange">
            </Grid>
        </muxc:TwoPaneView.Pane1>
        <muxc:TwoPaneView.Pane2>
            <Grid x:Name="Pane2Root"
                  Background="Green">
            </Grid>
        </muxc:TwoPaneView.Pane2>
    </muxc:TwoPaneView>
</Grid>
```

[image: two-pane-view]

Comment: You could submit an issue in the [WinUI issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues)

Comment: Ok, wanted to confirm that it is indeed wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Since Pane1 has no content or min width, Auto sizing gives it 0px of width in wide mode. Setting MinWidth will find that it appears when the window is wide enough.